# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Storage.put is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I'm currently using React and AWS where I'm trying to add a feature such that users can upload a profile picture. I've created the box so users can select the desired profile picture but after selecting the picture, I get an error message that says `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Storage.put is not a function`. Does anyone know what's going on? Here's the code I'm using for selecting the picture.

```
export default class Settings extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      image: "",
    };
  }

  onOpenFileDialog = () => {
    let fileInput = React.createRef();
    fileInput.current.click();
  };

  onProcessFile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    try {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({
        image: reader.result
      })
    };
    const { id } = await Auth.currentUserPoolUser();
    Storage.put(`${id}-profile.png`, file, {
      contentType: "image/png"
    })
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(err => alert(err));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="settings">
        <ControlLabel className="Label">Profile Picture: </ControlLabel>
        <FormGroup controlId="photo" bsSuze="large">
          <a href="">
            <input
              type="file"
              onChange={this.onProcessFile}
              ref={this.fileInput}
              hidden={true}
            />
          </a>
          <img src={this.state.image} alt="Profile" width="320" height="320" onClick={this.OnOpenFileDialog} />
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure you have imported `Storage` from aws amplify package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the Storage function is not configured properly to upload anything. I would retrace the steps you have taken to implement Storage to see what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Looks like it was a very simple issue with the storage function.

Comment: @BrandonMacLeod Can you mention what the solution was?